# Stochastic Exponential - Protter

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 37 at page 84 of the book [Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540003137) by P. Protter.

In the proof there is the following statement, referred to the *semimartingale* $X$:

(1) *"Since $X$ has cadlag paths, there are only a finite number of  $\ \ 's'$ such that $| \Delta X_s | >1/2$ on each compact interval (fixed $\omega$)"*

Why is this? I know that if $X$ has *cadlag* path then it has countably many jumps. Is the statement related to the fact of $X$ being a semimartingale and therefore composed by a local martingale and a finite variation process?

Another implication I am not sure about is:

(2) since $\log (V_t) \leq [X,X]_t$, it follows that $\log (V_t)$ is a process of finite variation.

Is it enough to say that if a process is bounded by a finite variation one, then the it is of finite variation as well?

[image]

Proof:

[image]

Comment: to $2)$ are there any other assumptions on $V_t$?

Comment: @user190080 I attached a screenshot of the proof in the question

Comment: Re (1): Any cadlag function $f: [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ has only finitely many jumps with jump size $> \epsilon$ for any fixed $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @saz but still, why is it enough to show that $\log(V_t)\leq [X,X]_t$ to conclude that $\log(V_t)$ is of finite variation as well? the rest is clear then...but don't see how this follows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Any càdlàg function $f: [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ has at most finitely many jumps with jump size $>\epsilon$ for any (fixed) $\epsilon>0$, see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1038282/).
2. The estimate "$\leq [X,X]_t$" is not used to conclude that $\log V_t$ is of bounded variation, but to show that the series $\sum_{s \leq t} (\log(1+U_s)-U_s)$ is absolutely convergent.

   Recall that a function $\alpha$ is of bounded variation if we can write $\alpha = \alpha^+- \alpha^-$ where both $\alpha^+$ and $\alpha^-$ are increasing functions. For brevity set $Y_s := \log(1+U_s)-U_s$. If we define $$\alpha_+(t) := \sum_{\substack{s \leq t \\ Y_s>0}} Y_s \qquad \text{and} \qquad \alpha^-(t) := \sum_{\substack{s \leq t \\ Y_s<0}} - Y_s,$$ then $$\log V_t = \alpha^+(t)-\alpha^-(t)$$ and $\alpha^+$, $\alpha^-$ are both increasing processes. This means that $\log V_t$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: clear as crystal

Answer (score 2):

**This is only an answer for a part of the question**

To answer your second question $2)$:

No, in general it's not true that a function bounded by a function of finite variation is itself of finite variation, for example take

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, x=0 \\ \sin(\frac{1}{x}), \text{otherwise}\end{cases} 
$$
which is not of [bounded variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) although $f(x)$ is clearly bounded by constant functions since $f(x)$ is bounded itself. So there have to be some other properties for $\log(V_t)$ then to conclude this statement.